# Write to file and Search file php

Tags: php, fwrite

i have a java applet that calls this url that links to a php script that SHOULD write to file but...no dice. i get a http 500 error. Any clue?

`http://127.0.0.1/DBoperations.php?operation=write&UserId=james&Score=10`

```
#DBoperations.php
<?php
$operation = $_REQUEST["operation"]
$UserId = $_REQUEST["Userid"];
$Score = $_REQUEST["Score"];

if (operation =="write"){
write();
}
if (operation =="read"){
read();
}

function write()
{
$myFile = "testsroce.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "$UserId - $Score";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
}

function read()
{
$file = new SplFileObject('testscores.txt');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINES);
$match = false;
foreach($file as $line){
if( false !== stripos( $line, $UserId ) ){
    $match = true;
    break;
}
}
if( true === $match ){
echo $file;
} else {
echo "No Match Found";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it intended that your "read" and "write" filenames are different?

Comment: @Kolink `testsroce` sounds legit xD

Comment: What error message does your PHP script show? Turn on error messages if necessary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after this line:

```
$operation = $_REQUEST["operation"]
```

Should be

```
$operation = $_REQUEST["operation"];
```

You are also missing a `$` sign in a few places, e.g.

```
if (operation =="write"){
```

Should be:

```
if ($operation =="write"){
```

Comment: Also look at your `write()` function. This statement `$stringData = "$UserId - $Score";` will error out. You may have to send the `$UserId` and `$Score` variables as parameters to the function.